# How to load .gz files to BigQuery when using Google Cloud Datalab?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

Wikipedia stores their logs files as .gz, and BigQuery is able to ingest .gz files.

How can I "move" this files to BigQuery when using Google Cloud Datalab?

(files at http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'm loading .gz from the web right now:

```
import gcp.bigquery as bq
import gcp.storage as storage

f = urllib.urlopen(url)   
storage.Bucket('mybucket').item(gcs_url).write_to(f.read(), 'application/x-gzip')
table = bq.Table('%s.%s' % (dataset_name, table_name)).create(schema=schema, overwrite = True)
table.load_async(
  'gs://mybucket/%s' % gcs_url, mode='overwrite', csv_delimiter=' ', quote='', max_bad_records=100)
```

This to download the gz files at https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/2015/2015-01/.

Observations:

- I couldn't find an easy way to download and upload a file. Instead, I'm holding the whole thing in RAM (~100GB). It works well for this use case, but not ideal for larger files.
- I create the table before loading data into it. I couldn't figure out how to do both at the same time (hence BigQuery has an empty table for a while).
- When I use load_async, I wish there was an easy way to wait for all of the jobs to finish.
- Any easy way to integrate https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/, so it pages me when the job is done?

(issue tracker https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/issues/198)

Comment: You can use gcp.bigquery.wait_any/wait_all to wait for your jobs to complete

Comment: And yes, we require you to create a Table object before the BQ table. That is because Table objects have methods like exists(), delete(), etc - i.e. they exist independently of whether or not the corresponding BQ table exists.

Answer (score 0):

For copying large files from some HTTP location, you have some options. You can invoke individual bash commands from within the notebook, and use a combination of wget and gsutil within a bash cell.

```
%%bash
mkdir -p /tmp/data
cd /tmp/data
wget [src url]
gsutil cp [local file] [gcs location]
```

You could even use python to generate a shell script if you want to enumerate the individual files, write it out and then invoke that from the bash shell.

Or Storage Transfer service. See Transfer until Cloud Storage in dev console. I believe there is an API for this, but we didn't build any python wrapper for it. At least not yet.

---

Does BQ support creating and loading the table in one shot. If so we should make sure our API can do that. Can you file a bug for that if it is?

---

For waiting on jobs returned from load_async, see gcp.bigquery.wait_all/any.

---

Monitoring/alerting on job completion -- good idea. I am not completely sure whether that is a Datalab thing or the underlying jobs (eg. load job in BQ) ought to do that. The reason: you might kill your Datalab kernel, or even the instance, so you really want the job to notify, rather than Datalab monitor the completion of the job. However, no disagreement on having this sort of integration.